# What is the best way to connect Realm and SwiftBond

Tags: ios, swift, architecture, realm, swiftbond

I love [Realm](http://realm.io) and I love [Bond](https://github.com/SwiftBond/Bond). Both of them makes app creation a joy. So I was wondering what is the best way to connect Realm and Bond? 
 In Realm we can store basic types such as `Int`, `String`, e.g. But in Bond we work with `Dynamic`s and `Bond`s. The only way that I found to connect Realm and Bond is following:

```
class TestObject: RLMObject {

   dynamic var rlmTitle: String = ""
   dynamic var rlmSubtitle: String = ""

   var title: Dynamic<String>
   var subtitle: Dynamic<String>

   private let titleBond: Bond<String>!
   private let subtitleBond: Bond<String>!

   init(title: String, subtitle: String) {
      self.title = Dynamic<String>(title)
      self.subtitle = Dynamic<String>(subtitle)

      super.init()

      self.titleBond = Bond<String>() { [unowned self] title in self.rlmTitle = title }
      self.subtitleBond = Bond<String>() { [unowned self] subtitle in self.rlmSubtitle = subtitle }

      self.title ->> titleBond
      self.subtitle ->> subtitleBond
   }
}
```

But it surely lacks simplicity and elegance and produces a lot of boiler code. Is there any way to do this better?

Comment: Any updates on this question? Is there an official way of achieving this now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been thinking about this for three days and came up with nearly perfect solution, which does not employ any boilerplate code. First of all I have created a super class for a realm model's wrapper:

```
class BondRealmBaseClass {

   private var realmModel: RLMObject!
   private let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
   private var bonds = NSMutableArray()

   init(){
      realmModel = createRealmModel()
      realm.beginWriteTransaction()
      realm.addObject(realmModel)
      realm.commitWriteTransaction()
      createBonds()
   }

   init(realmModel: RLMObject){
      self.realmModel = realmModel
      createBonds()
   }

   func createBondFrom<T>(from: Dynamic<T>, toModelKeyPath keyPath: String){
      from.value = realmModel.valueForKeyPath(keyPath) as T
      let bond = Bond<T>() { [unowned self] value in
         self.realm.beginWriteTransaction()
         self.realmModel.setValue(value as NSObject, forKey: keyPath)
         self.realm.commitWriteTransaction()
      }
      from ->| bond
      bonds.addObject(bond)
   }

   //MARK: - Should be overriden by super classes
   func createBonds(){ fatalError("should be implemented in supreclass") }
   func createRealmModel() -> RLMObject{ fatalError("should be implemented in supreclass") }
}
```

After that for each realm model I create two classes, first is the actual realm model, which stores all properties:

```
class RealmTodoModel: RLMObject { 
   dynamic var title = ""
   dynamic var date = NSDate()
}
```

and a second one is the wrapper around realm model:

```
class TodoModel : BondRealmBaseClass{
   let title = Dynamic("")
   let date = Dynamic(NSDate())

   override func createBonds(){
      createBondFrom(title, toModelKeyPath: "title")
      createBondFrom(date, toModelKeyPath: "date")
   }

   override func createRealmModel() -> RLMObject { return RealmTodoModel() }
}
```

And this two classes is actually all is needed to link `Realm` and `Bond`: creating new `TodoModel` will actually add to Realm new `RealmTodoModel` and all changes made with `TodoModel`'s `title` and `date` will be automatically saved to corresponding `Realm` model!

### **EDIT**

I added some functionality and posted this as a framework on GitHub. Here is the [link](https://github.com/hip4yes/Bond-Realm).

Comment: Looks like the link is no longer valid. Any updates on your framework?

Answer (score 6):

With Realm supporting KVO and Bond 4, you can extend Realm objects to provide Observable variants. There is some boilerplate to it, but it's clean and without hacks.

```
class Dog: Object {
  dynamic var name = ""
  dynamic var birthdate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 1)
}

extension Dog {

  class ObservableDog {
    let name: Observable<String>
    let birthdate: Observable<NSDate>

    init(dog: Dog) {
      name = Observable(object: dog, keyPath: "name")
      birthdate = Observable(object: dog, keyPath: "birthdate")
    }
  }

  func observableVariant() -> Dog.ObservableDog {
    return ObservableDog(dog: self)
  }
}
```

Than you'll be able to do:

```
let myDog = Dog().observableVariant()

myDog.name.observe { newName in
  print(newName)
}

myDog.name.bindTo(nameLabel.bnd_text)

realm.write {
  myDog.name.value = "Jim"
}
```

Comment: is something similar possible where you have `var List<Food> = List()` on Dog? Namely, observe changes to this list.

Answer (score 1):

You could likely simplify the pattern you're using somewhat if you used
default property values:

```
  class TestObject: RLMObject {

     dynamic var rlmTitle = ""
     dynamic var rlmSubtitle = ""

     var title: Dynamic<String>
     var subtitle: Dynamic<String>

     private let titleBond = Bond<String>() { [unowned self] title in self.rlmTitle = title }
     private let subtitleBond = Bond<String>() { [unowned self] subtitle in self.rlmSubtitle = subtitle }

     init(title: String, subtitle: String) {
        self.title = Dynamic<String>(title)
        self.subtitle = Dynamic<String>(subtitle)
        self.title ->> titleBond
        self.subtitle ->> subtitleBond

        super.init()
     }
  }
```

You could remove another two lines of code if Bond's `->>` operator returned the
left value so you could do `self.title = Dynamic<String>(title) ->> titleBond`.

But ultimately, until Swift has native language support for KVO or an equivalent observation mechanism, you're sadly going to have to write some amount of boilerplate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Actually I found better way to do this, please look at my answer. If are very welcome to improve it